# How to read and write data in Google Cloud Bigtable in PySpark application?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-bigtable

I am using Spark on a Google Cloud Dataproc cluster and I would like to access Bigtable in a PySpark job. Do we have any Bigtable connector for Spark like Google BigQuery connector?

How can we access Bigtable from a PySpark application?

Answer (score 6):

Cloud Bigtable is usually best accessed from Spark using the [Apache HBase APIs](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/bigtable-and-hbase).

HBase currently only provides Hadoop MapReduce I/O formats. These can be accessed from Spark (or PySpark) using the `SparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD` methods. However converting the records into something usable in Python is difficult.

HBase is developing Spark SQL APIs, but these have not been integrated in a released version. Hortonworks has a [Spark HBase Connector](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc), but it compiles against Spark 1.6 (which requires Cloud Dataproc version 1.0) and I have not used it, so I cannot speak to how easy it is to use.

Alternatively you could use a Python based Bigtable client, and simply use PySpark for parallelism.

Comment: Hello Patric. I am trying to write to bigtable using pyspark. Is there any example how it can be done using SparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD ?